# How do you access the camera besides using CTRL+ALT+0?

Tags: camera

I've been trying to use CTRL + ALT + 0, but it doesn't work at all for me.

Comment: That key combination aligns the current camera to the current view in your 3D viewport (assuming you are using the Numpad zero).  Are you sure that's what you wish to do?  To simply jump in and out of camera view, hit Numpad 0 without any modifier keys.

Comment: doesn't ctrl+0 (ctrl+numpad zero) set any object as the active camera? In this way you switch between different cameras very fast and easily...

Answer (score 3):

Either Select it from the 3D scene or outliner and make it active, or set it as active directly from the *Scene* tab in the *Properties Window*

[image]